# links are opening in webview i want to open in default browser in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have a WebView and I wanted to when someone click on a link it should open in a browser not in my app. How can I do that?

I want to show a first webpage but when someone click on it it should open in a new browser that's all I want. How can i do that?

Here is the code that I am using

```
package com.packagename.weebly.free_recharge_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class tab2 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup                               container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    // This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's cache
    // But it didn't work for me without this line.
    // UPDATE: no hardcoded path. Thanks to Kevin Hawkins
    //  String appCachePath = this.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    //  Log.e(TAG, "appCachePath = " + appCachePath);
    // webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

    return view;
    }
}
```

after adding your code @eugene

```
package com.freerechargeapp.weebly.free_recharge_app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class tab2 extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup          container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    // This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's     cache
    // But it didn't work for me without this line.
    // UPDATE: no hardcoded path. Thanks to Kevin Hawkins
  //  String appCachePath = this.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
  //  Log.e(TAG, "appCachePath = " + appCachePath);
   // webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



    // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.loadUrl("google.com");

    return view;



}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

or add this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello @eugene after deleting `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` it's opening it's opening in browser and working in android 4.4 but in lollipop 5.1 it's not working when you click on a link it's opening in my app webView.

Comment: Hello @eugene even after adding this code it's not working on lollipop it's opening in webVIew i have updated my code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a class in your activity.

```
private class AppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
```

2) `setWebViewClient` with newly created class. You already have one, that you should delete and replace with following.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Hi @Sharj can you provide a screenshot, gif or video how to do this actually i'm a newbie i don't know which code i have to paste and where any screenshot , gif or video tutorila would be great

Answer (score 0):

[From](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation),

> When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView, **the default behavior is for Android to launch an application that handles URLs. Usually, the default web browser opens and loads the destination URL.**

The default behavior is, when a link is clicked in your WebView, android will launch it with Intent.ACTION_VIEW. The default behavior is changed by providing a WebViewClient to your WebView

Simply remove the WebViewClient that you have provided to your WebView and your app will work with the default flow.

Comment: i deleted the webViewClient and it's opening urls in browser in android 4.4 but in android 5.1 it's opening in my app webView what else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The Comment in your code is telling you that this will not open the code in a new link.

```
// Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

You Need to Override the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
  view.loadUrl(url);
  return false;
}
});
```

A return value of true means the host application handles the URL, while return false means the current WebView handles the URL