# Webview opening certain link in browser

Tags: java, android

I have an app that opens my webpages in the same intent and within the same webview. Now, I have a certain page that I want it to open in browser when user requests it. Is that possible?
Here is my Code:

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://mywebpage.me");
    String url = myWebView.getUrl();

myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and if the user navigates to https//:mywebpage.me/About.html i want it to show in browser.

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398364/links-are-opening-in-webview-i-want-to-open-in-default-browser-in-android-studio?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen for navigation event.

1. Create **WebViewClient**

   ```
   private class MyClient extends WebViewClient {

       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           if(url.equals(PUT_YOUR_URL_HERE)) {
               startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
               return true;
           }  

           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass it to **WebView**

   ```
   myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());
   ```

By the way, this method was deprecated in API level 24.

Comment: Really glad to hear that! Please, consider accepting my answer.